# How to access CloudWatch Event data from triggered Fargate task?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I read the docs on how to [Run an Amazon ECS Task When a File is Uploaded to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html). However, this document stops short of explaining how to get the bucket/key values from the triggering event from **within** the Fargate task code itself. How can that be done?

Comment: Looks like it's not a good example for Cloudwatch events. ECS task generally is for long running server. Lambda/Batch is much fit for S3. object putting events.

Comment: I hit the wall there too, i want to schedule a cloudwatch event for my fargate task with a constant json input to the task. How to read it in the code?

Comment: I found this which does a good job of showing the steps... https://medium.com/@bowbaq/trigger-an-ecs-job-when-an-s3-upload-completes-3559c44c37d1

Comment: That’s brutal, and not everyone uses Terraform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you still need the answer for this one. But I did something similar to what Steven1978 mentioned but only using CloudFormation.

The config you're looking for is the **InputTransformer**. Check this example for a YAML CloudFormation template for an Event Rule:

```
rEventRuleForFileUpload:
Type: AWS::Events::Rule
Properties:
  Description: "EventRule"
  State: "ENABLED"
  EventPattern:
    source:
      - "aws.s3"
    detail-type:
      - 'AWS API Call via CloudTrail'
    detail:
      eventSource:
        - s3.amazonaws.com
      eventName:
        - "PutObject"
        - "CompleteMultipartUpload"
      requestParameters:
        bucketName: "{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME}"

  Targets:
    - Id: '{YOUR_ECS_CLUSTER_ID}'
      Arn: !Sub "arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:cluster/${NAME_OF_YOUR_CLUSTER_RESOURCE}"
      RoleArn: !GetAtt {YOUR_ROLE}.Arn
      EcsParameters:
        TaskCount: 1
        TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref {YOUR_TASK_DEFINITION}
        LaunchType: FARGATE

        {... WHATEVER CONFIG YOU MIGHT HAVE...}

      InputTransformer:
        InputPathsMap:
          s3_bucket: "$.detail.requestParameters.bucketName"
          s3_key: "$.detail.requestParameters.key"
        InputTemplate: '{ "containerOverrides": [ { "name": "{THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_CONTAINER_DEFINITION}", "environment": [ { "name": "EVENT_BUCKET", "value": <s3_bucket> }, { "name": "EVENT_OBJECT_KEY", "value": <s3_key> }] } ] }'
```

With this approach, you'll be able to get the s3 bucket name (EVENT_BUCKET) and the s3 object key (EVENT_OBJECT_KEY) as environment variables inside your container.

The info isn't very clear, indeed, but here are some sources I used to finally get it working:

Container Override;
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerOverride.html

InputTransformer:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_InputTransformer.html#API_InputTransformer_Contents